# Attempting to change CSS using document.getElementById not working?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to change the CSS of a *display:none* to a *display:block* using the following command:

```
document.getElementById["pop-up"].style.display="block";
```

The problem is, despite defining the pop-up id in the css (see below), and following other instructions similar to this problem, I've not been able to get it to change.

```
#pop-up {
    display: none;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _document.getElementById("pop-up")_ . Note the `(` & `)`, but you have used `[` & `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` is a **function** (not an object where every element with an ID exists as a property).

You need to call it with `()` and not access properties with `[]`

---

Make sure you open the Developer Tools in your browser and read the console. It would have told you that `document.getElementById["pop-up"]` was undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the square brackets with parentheses;

```
document.getElementById("pop-up").style.display="block";
```